# Multiple plots side by side on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to put four plots together on the same plot. I can easily arrange each plot in a grid but I would like to be able to see them in the same plot.

Essentially I want it to look a little bit like this graph
[multiple bars for each item and multiple items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlNsR.png)

The code for the plots I want is

```
  ggplot(SexInfo, aes(x = C_Sex, y = C_SexInfo_7)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "summary", fun = mean, fill = c("cadetblue", "darkgreen"))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = .4)+
  ylim(0,6)
```

and I have the same code for 3 other plots. I now want them all to be plot on the same plot instead of placing four plots in a grid.

Comment: This will likely require reshaping your data. Please post some of your data using `dput(SexInfo)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).